# Why can't my vector access the variables in my nested structs?

Tags: c++, variables, vector, struct, linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

struct record{
    int id;
    string fName;   
};
struct cells{
    list<record> rec[100];
};
vector<cells> hp(100);

int main()
{
    hp[0].rec[0].front().fName = "jon"; // problem occurs here
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 structs. The first struct, struct `record`, is composed of 2 regular variables. In struct 2, I have a linked list of type `record`, which includes all the variable listed in struct 1. Why is it that when ever I attempt to access  a variable in the structs, using my vector, I get the error:

```
"linked list iterator not dereferencable?"
```

Comment: to signify the area where the problem occurs. I also changed to code to show the size of the vector and the list, still doesn't work

Comment: @chucknorris: What "size of the list" are you talking about? You never put anything in your lists. Your lists are empty. And you attempt to call `front()` on an empty list.

Comment: @Pubby - nobody asks chucknorris why he has `**`.

Answer (score 0):

The error takes place because all of your lists are *empty*. It is illegal to call `front()` on an empty container.

Comment: Chuck Norris can call `front()` on an empty container.

Comment: Chuck Norris can call `front` even if there is no container.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right,

change

```
vector<cells> hp(100);
```

to

```
vector<cells> hp(100, cells{{list<record>(1, record())}});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
struct cells
{
    list<record> rec;

    cells():rec(100) {}
};

vector<cells> hp(100);


int main()
{
    hp.front().rec.front().fName = "jon";
    return 0;
}
```

In your code, if you have an array of 100 `list`s, you essentially have 100 lists, each of them uninitialized. You don't need 100 `list`s. You need 1 `list` with 100 `records`. I have shown above how to do this.

This compiles and also works fine.

Comment: @chucknorris - If it works accept the answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . This will add to your reputation and also mine. And it will also serve as a record of which answer was correct for you.

Answer (score 0):

cells is an array of 100 list... and every one of them is uninitialized.